# How to sync keychain over iCloud

Tags: ios, icloud, keychain

I wan't to store sensitive data for my app in the keychain. I'd also like this to sync over devices, using iCloud.

According to Apple this is possible:

> Does iCloud Keychain work with third-party apps?
>
> Yes. Developers can update their apps to work with iCloud Keychain.
>   Passwords saved by those apps are kept up to date on all devices that
>   use the app and are using iOS 7.0.3 or later or OS X Mavericks v10.9
>   or later.

However, I can't find any documentation about what is needed by the app. Will all content of the keychain be synced if the user has enabled iCloud Keychain?

Comment: Thanks for the down vote. What's the problem with the question?

Comment: Seriously, If there's something wrong with the question I'll be happy to rephrase it. Just let me know what the problem is :]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to set the `kSecAttrSynchronizable` attribute when adding any item that you want to be synced. I would suggest using a wrapper library such as [KeychainAccess](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/KeychainAccess) (in swift) or [UICKeyChainStore](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/UICKeyChainStore) (in Obj-C), as it largely facilitates the handling of the keychain and of the various attributes (they both provide a `synchronizable` property)

Comment: Does it forces the re-sync with iCloud even if the user has the Keychain iCloud disabled? https://www.imore.com/how-use-icloud-keychain-iphone-and-ipad