# How does spotify detect your account data without login?

Tags: ios

Just stumbled over a new Spotify behavior. I installed Spotify on a new device and instead of a login screen I was already logged in and it displayed my home screen.

How does it retrieve the login data credentials?

Is this done via a synced keychain?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33775569/how-to-sync-keychain-over-icloud ? I'd guess also that's a iCloud Synced KeyChain...